# Route not found error when using webform_rest to upload files

Tags: webforms

I want to upload a file using webform_rest API as described here. [#2899902](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest/issues/2899902). But it gives me `415 Unsupported Media Type` error as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: Console error screenshot]

**Here is my code**

```
  methods: {
    addImage() {
      this.dropFiles = event.target.files[0];
    },

    submitResume() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", this.dropFiles, this.dropFiles.name);

      axios
        .get("https://example.com/rest/session/token")
        .then(tokenResponce => {
          this.formToken = tokenResponce.data;
        });

      axios
        .post(
          "https://example.com/webform_rest/job_applications/upload/resume?_format=json",
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              Accept: "json",
              "Content-Type": "application/hal+json",
              "Content-Disposition": "file; filename = full.pdf",
              "X-CSRF-Token": this.formToken
            }
          }
        )
        .then(response => {
          this.submitForm(response);
        });
    },

    async submitForm(response) {
      if (this.page === "singlejob") {
        var position = this.jobs.title;
      } else {
        var position = this.position;
      }

      let config = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "json",
          "Content-Type": "application/hal+json"
        }
      };

      this.isLoading = true;

      axios
        .post(
          `https://example.com/webform_rest/submit?_format=json`,
          {
            webform_id: "job_applications",
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            position: position,
            resume: response.data.fid[0].value
          },
          config
        )
        .then(response => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          if (response.data.sid) {
            this.$router.push({
              path: "/thank-you"
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(error => (this.isLoading = false));
    }
  }
```

Need help here.
Thanks

Comment: Did you applied the patch provided in that issue?

Comment: @d70rr3s Yes Applied

Comment: Could you please check that the endpoint is enabled properly configured using the Rest UI module https://www.drupal.org/project/restui

Comment: Yes that is also enabled as you can see in the screenshot https://i.ibb.co/Qffnch4/Screen-Shot-2020-01-21-at-6-34-34-PM.png

Comment: I'm reviewing your code and I see that you are uploading the file using ?_format=json but your are sending the form directly instead of building the request payload, that would be the problem since the _format parameter tells Drupal how to handle your request and is consistent with your payload (multipart/form data). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Also check this https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest/issues/2899902#comment-13239800 on the issue, they are using Content-Type: application/octect+stream for the payload instead of hal+json as you are doing in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. two things I was missing.

1. Make sure you accept all the operations / JSON requests from here
   /admin/config/services/jsonapi
2. I was confused with "binary file data". So basically you don't have
   to do anything with the file. No formData, No base64, just pass your
   file variable as it is.

And it worked.

Thanks